# Report Header in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, rdl, reportbuilder

I apologize if I am missing something obvious guys, but I am having a heck of a time figuring out how to add a report header (not page header) to a report.  I want a header that shows up on the first page and only the first page.

Again, I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the report Header will repeat on each page. If you want to only display it on the first page, just add whatever you want to display as a Header to the top of the report body outside of any repeating groups (Table, List, etc).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense...and was obvious :)  Thanks Ian, just a case of staring at the same problem long enough to complicate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just place a `Textbox` at the start of the data region and give it a name as you may wish. It will act like a `Report Header`.

More on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2010/12/28/report-headers-and-footers-with-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx):